# Discrete Math Help. Identify whether its true or false.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

This is what i have for part a but not sure if this is correct. 
a) There is a $x$ and $y$ for all integers, that $xy = y$.

b) For every $x$ is an integer, there is a $y$ for all integers, that $xy = 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a)$ is true, take $x = 1$, and $1\cdot y = y, \forall y$, but $b)$ is false, take $x = 3$, there is no $y$ being integer that $3y = 1$. If you want to write it as a sentence: $\exists x \in \mathbb{Z}\text{   }\text{   } \forall y \in \mathbb{Z}\text{  }  xy \neq 1$

Comment: So how would i write that out in a sentence?

Comment: There is a x and y for all integers, that xy = y, is true. If x = 1 and 1(y) =y, xy=y. ?

Comment: Thank you! This helped greatly!

Comment: @spatel I would phrase the result as "There exists an integer $x$ (namely the number $1$) which has the property that regardless what integer $y$ you pick, you have $xy=y$."  Using a more building block phrasing, "There exists an $x$ such that for every $y$ you have $xy=y$."  Your phrasing sounds like "there exists an $x$ and there exists a $y$..." but in that phrasing it sounds like there might potentially be only one such $y$ while we intend that $y$ can be anything.

Comment: @spatel For the negation of the second, "there exists an $x$ (for example $3$) such that regardless what $y$ you pick $xy\neq 1$."  Before the negation it sounds like "every integer $x$ has some integer $y$ such that $xy=1$."  (which we showed not to be true by counterexample).

Comment: @JMoravitz ok thank you. And does the sentence for part b sound correct?